# How to optimally get sorted records, when the sort column requires computation from a secondary service?

Tags: sql, sorting, transactions, microservices, aggregation

Imagine I'm a bank and I want a dashboard that shows our "top spenders" with data updating throughout the day.

Currently I query the database for all our customer IDs, and pass all those IDs to a service which calculates how much they've spent today. If I have 10,000 customers, it must make 10,000 calculations.

Then I pick the Top 10 and show them in the dashboard. 9,990 calculations were useless, but we can't know which ones until they're complete.

Is there some way to improve the performance? I can't pre-calculate because customers are making new purchases all the time, and the list should be dynamic.

What if the results are very consistent day-to-day? As in, the Top 10 spenders are almost always in yesterday's Top 20. We could store the prior day's top spenders, and only calculate those 20 to find the Top 10, but if someone jumps from #25 to #9, they would be missing from our Top 10 if we use that algorithm.

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Why are you calculating the spend for all customers individually rather than in one query i.e. sum (spend) group by customer?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of asking another service for all customers, have this service subscribe to customer created/deleted events from that service, and have it store the customer info in its database. So, it will not need to inefficiently query all the customers every time to compute the top spenders.